# get first characters of expansion parameter of find command

Tags: terminal, mac, bash

I have a huge collection of images and I would like to put them in folders matching their first 3 charachers+.jpg extension.

So i would like to grab `4_1_0002.png` file (all the files starting with 4_1) and put it in the `4_1_.jpg` folder. Similarly I would like to grab `4_2_0002.png` file (all the files starting with 4_2) and put it in the `4_2_.jpg` folder.

All those files that I would like to sort are now in one huge folder.
I expected to use a find command, but I don't know how to extract the first three characters from {} expansion parameter.

```
find . -type f -ok echo mv {} "path/first3char.jpg" \;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to put .png files in a folder with a .jpg extension, why not a folder with a .png extension?

Comment: At first I was working with jpg's, but than switched to pngs. Didnt bother to change the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all your files are in the same directory and the filenames are reasonable sane, something like

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*png' |
     while read line; do
         echo mv "$line" "path/${line:2:3}.jpg/"
     done
```

Run the command first as written (including the `echo`) to check whether the result makes sense. Then remove the `echo` and rerun.

Comment: While I did up-vote the answer, nonetheless I'd add a condition in the form of testing the directory exists, e.g., `[[ -d path/${line:2:3}.jpg ]]`, and use it like, e.g., `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*png' | while read line; do [[ -d path/${line:2:3}.jpg ]] && echo mv "$line" "path/${line:2:3}.jpg/"; done`. That said, obviously if the directory doesn't exist it won't move the file. The reason for the suggestion is any time I use a wildcard, as in, e.g., `'*png'` in the `find` command, I like to make subsequent code that will act upon the results of a wildcard `find` conditional.

Comment: I mention this because as an example, if one accidentally (or intensional) left the trailing slash off of `"path/${line:2:3}.jpg/"` so as to be `"path/${line:2:3}.jpg`", it would rename a file by moving it to `${line:2:3}.jpg` as a file not into a directory because the directory didn't exist.